# How do I skip a certain part of a for loop without skiping it at the end in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
for d in 'EWNS':
            if d=='E' and j < len(m[i])-1 and m[i][j+1] != 1:
                print("E")
                childCell=(i,j+1)
                m[i][j+1] = 2
            if d=='W' and j>0 and m[i][j-1] != 1:
                print("W")
                childCell=(i,j-1)
                m[i][j-1] = 2
            if d=='N' and i>0 and  m[i-1][j] != 1:
                print("N")
                childCell=(i-1,j)
                m[i-1][j] = 2
            if d=='S' and i<len(m)-1 and  m[i+1][j] != 1:
                print("S")
                childCell=(i+1,j)
                m[i+1][j] = 2
            else:
                print("else")
                continue

            temp_g_score=g_score[i][j]+1
            print(temp_g_score)
            temp_f_score=temp_g_score+h(childCell)
            print(temp_f_score)
            ...
```

I want to iterate through  this for loop 4 times checking each if statement once. If the statement I check does not evaluate to true, I want to skip to the next iteration of the for loop without going through the code that comes after the group of if statements. That is to say, I want to run the last few lines of code only when one of the if statments is true, so from 0 to for times 4, up to one for each if statement.

To this effect, I added and else statement, but It doesn't seem to be helping, as the output I get suggests that I am always skipping the rest of the code.

```
E
else
W
else
N
else
else
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your `else` only applies to the last `if`, not the previous 3 `if`s. Leave the first `if` as it is and change the others to `elif`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the for-loop. It's an unnecessary complication.

```
def update_scores()
    temp_g_score=g_score[i][j]+1
    print(temp_g_score)
    temp_f_score=temp_g_score+h(childCell)
    print(temp_f_score)
    
if j < len(m[i])-1 and m[i][j+1] != 1:
    print("E")
    childCell=(i,j+1)
    m[i][j+1] = 2
    update_scores()
if j>0 and m[i][j-1] != 1:
    print("W")
    childCell=(i,j-1)
    m[i][j-1] = 2
    update_scores()
if i>0 and  m[i-1][j] != 1:
    print("N")
    childCell=(i-1,j)
    m[i-1][j] = 2
    update_scores()
if i<len(m)-1 and  m[i+1][j] != 1:
    print("S")
    childCell=(i+1,j)
    m[i+1][j] = 2
    update_scores()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like following (I have not your data, so I remove something):

#### Code

```py
for d in 'EWNS':
            if d=='E':
                print("E")
            elif d=='W':
                print("W")
            elif d=='N':
                print("N")
            elif d=='S':
                print("S")
            else:
                print("else")
```

#### Output

```
E
W
N
S
```

If I have answered your question to your satisfaction, then consider accepting the answer.

Thanks.